# Hide input html for password with *

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I want to hide to password input with asterisk (*). When I use following type :

```
<input type="password"/>
```

It hides with '.'(circle) but I want to hide with '*'. How could I change hidden marks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not possible to change the symbol using some attributes. It depends on the userAgent and OS. But you still manipulate with the few tweaks.

```js
const inputEl = document.querySelector('input');

const dummyEl = document.querySelector('#dummy');

const resultEl = document.querySelector('#result');

inputEl.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
  const dummyText = Array(inputEl.value.length).fill('*').join('');
  dummyEl.innerHTML = dummyText;
  resultEl.innerHTML = inputEl.value;
})
```

```css
div {
  position: relative;
}
input {
  color: transparent;
}
span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 7px;
  left: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="password" />
  <span id="dummy"></span>
</div>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't do that.

> The element is presented as a one-line plain text editor control in which the text is obscured so that it cannot be read, usually by replacing each character with a symbol such as the asterisk ("*") or a dot ("•"). **This character will vary depending on the user agent and OS.**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/password